# "Не" с причастиями при слове "невдалеке"

Tags: частица-не, грамматика, причастия

Пахло гарью **незатухающего** *невдалеке* пожара. ([Источник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/8920/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C))

Почему **не** с причастием *затухающего* пишется слитно? Здесь же есть зависимое наречие *невдалеке*, и можно задать вопрос от причастия "*не затухающего **где***?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте рассуждать от противного. Попробуем написать раздельно: "Пахло гарью не затухающего невдалеке пожара".

Очевидно, что напрашивается (требуется?) противопоставление: "не затухающего невдалеке пожара[*, а небольшого костерка*]." Поучилось, что слова "затухающий невдалеке пожар" образуют одно целое, а "не" даёт к этому целому отрицание.

Но ведь смысл-то не тот: говорилось о незатухающем пожаре, находящемся невдалеке.
Поэтому пишем слитно: "незатухающий".

P.S. Приведённое источнике предложение отдаёт какой-то неправильностью. Как и "не жаренное на костре мясо". У одного меня такое ощущение?

Answer (score 2):

Зависимое слово – слабый признак. Гораздо сильнее – возможность подобрать синоним без НЕ.

А вообще, нужно усвоить всего один принцип, из которого и следуют все многочисленные правила правописания НЕ с любыми частями речи. Вот он: есть отрицание – пишем раздельно, нет отрицания – слитно. Здесь явно нет отрицания: незатухающий пожар = продолжающийся пожар.

Comment: "Лежало *не жаренное* на костре мясо." Тут тоже не чувствуеся отрицание. Но писать *нежаренное* всё равно нельзя.

Comment: Вы придумали совершенно искусственное, неживое предложение. В том смысле, что так по-русски не говорят.

Answer (score 2):

Пахло гарью незатухающего невдалеке пожара.

Вечная проблема русской орфографии - это вопрос о влиянии зависимых слов на написание НЕ с причастиями. Это правило кажется формальным, оно (как мы видим) не всегда действует, его (как думают реформаторы) хорошо бы отменить. Поэтому так важно найти связь между смыслом, грамматикой и  правилом, только тогда формальный признак наличия зависимого слова будет казаться обоснованным.

Одиночные причастия пишутся с НЕ слитно, так как  с помощью приставки НЕ мы образуем от причастия новое слово: непросохшая (мокрая)одежда. Здесь причастие близко по значению к прилагательному, так как обозначает постоянный признак (в нем отсутствует временной фактор). Но вот появляется зависимое слово: еще не просохшая одежда, теперь временной фактор налицо, частица НЕ отрицает действие, протекающее во времени.

Делать такой анализ каждый раз неудобно, поэтому мы и пользуемся формальным правилом: есть зависимое слово - значит, пишем НЕ раздельно. Но иногда правило не действует, а почему? Можно предположить, что в этом случае зависимое слово "неправильное", то есть оно не обеспечивает переход постоянного признака в признак по действию.

В приведенном примере наречие "невдалеке" имеет значение места, но не времени, поэтому вполне допустимо не учитывать его при определении формы написания НЕ. Сравнить: пахло гарью до сих пор не затухающего пожара (раздельное написание НЕ).

Comment: "Не возвращённая *автору* рукопись." "Не изданные *при жизни писателя* главы." -- здесь зависимые слова не влияют на временной фактор, но всё равно "отбивают" **не** от причастия.

Answer (score 0):

Незатухающего здесь вместе потому, что самодостотаточное, законченное по смыслу. Раздельно бы писалось в случае противоставления корню "тух": "не затухающего, а неизменно оживающего (возгорающегося, вспыхивавшего) невдалеке пожара"